# All products leading to 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9

i recently uploaded my magento site from local. But afetr i faced some issues. Firstly all my products are showing on the home page. But any time i try to view them on their own page, it gives me 404 error. What i noticed is a custom module SM Shop By isn't indexing in my index manager. Av tried several solutions i found online to correct it. But no result. Pls help Asap. http://www.innoshoppers.com.ng/

Comment: Have you reindexed your URL rewrites?

Comment: yes i have. it reindexed well. no issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to database truncate `core_url_rewrite` table and clear cache

Then reindex all from

**admin->System->Index Management**